# painless: check if an individual document contains a key

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I'm using [painless](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/5.5/index.html) to filter documents with Elastic 5.5

### Problem

Using "painless", find documents with `strings` field.

#### Expected Results

Only documents with `strings` field are returned

#### Actual Results

All documents are returned.

#### Observation

All documents are returned, as long as there's a document with `strings` field. This could be a caching issue of some sort.

### TestCase

#### Fixtures

```json
PUT /test_idx

POST /test_idx/t/1
{
      "strings": ["hello", "world"]
}

POST /test_idx/t/2
{
      "numbers": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

#### Query

```json
GET /test_idx/_search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "filter": [
            {
               "script": {
                  "script": {
                     "lang": "painless",
                     "inline": "return doc.containsKey(params.keypath)",
                     "params": {"keypath": "strings"}
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

#### Actual Response

```json
{
   "took": 5,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_idx",
            "_type": "t",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 0,
            "_source": {
               "numbers": [
                  1,
                  2,
                  3
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_idx",
            "_type": "t",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0,
            "_source": {
               "strings": [
                  "hello",
                  "world"
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

### Expected Response

```json
{
   "took": 5,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_idx",
            "_type": "t",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0,
            "_source": {
               "strings": [
                  "hello",
                  "world"
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try this, even though it is strongly discouraged to overuse painless for performance reasons

```json
GET /test_idx/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "lang": "painless",
              "inline": "return doc[params.keypath].value != null",
              "params": {
                "keypath": "strings.keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this works, yet `null` could be a valid field value. which may lead to incorrect results… Yes, we're observing the performance, so far it's acceptable…

Comment: when a field has a null value it is not at all indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you require painless to do so? This can be easily done by [exists query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/query-dsl-exists-query.html)

```json
{
  "query": {
    "exists": {
      "field": "strings"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Using painless to do more complex checks, ie: field `strings` exactly equals ["hello", "world"]. 
Yes, `exists` works, but still wondering why isn't the `containsKey` functioning...

Comment: If you have something complex I would suggest you to change the way you are storing data. For example instead of storing values as `array`, consider `nested` object. Try to avoid the use of script as relying more and more on script will degrade the performance.

Comment: We're benchmarking and will see whether it's acceptable. Also don't see why painless can't be compiled into the same underlying AST JSON pseudo AST gets compiled to.

Comment: @Maryan the problem when using scripting is that the script (painless = java) has to be executed against each document and can't leverage all the benefits that the inverted index provides.